# PNG image gets cropped when using the Facebook SDK send dialog

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, meta-tags

I have a website that contains a png image in the Facebook open graph meta tags. It displays correctly in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) and on messenger.

I want to enable the user to use the Facebook SDK's [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog) to share the page. This gives a popup (an iframe) that contains the image but this time it is cropped on the right, i.e. the image is too wide for the container.

This is my SDK code:

```
FB.ui({
  display: "iframe",
  link:, "https://example.com",
  method: "send"
}));
```

I have tried:

- Experimenting with the actual width and height of the png. This changes the way it is cropped but I never had a good result.
- Changing the image width and height in the meta tags (i.e. to wrong values).
- Styling with CSS. This is not possible since it's an iframe whose url is a different domain. I could use a true popup instead of an iframe (`display` option in the send dialog) but I think that's more susceptible to popup blockers etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Other than following the best practices outlined here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images, there isn’t much you can do.

Comment: I do follow these, still cropped unfortunately.

Comment: Well I guess you could try with an image of the same aspect ratio as the cropped one to begin with, and see if that gives results that are more to your liking.

Comment: I did try this; it's not completely straightforward because the (cropped) image is also scaled. I took the cropped width and scaled it back to the corresponding width of the original image, but using these dimensions the result was another differently cropped image.